# Vue js router-view selection

Tags: vue.js

I have parent component which has

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Inside of parent component there is another component and it also has a

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Both are bound to `/login` route

When I go to `/login` route it loads both of them. I would like to skip first/parent router-view for loading the component.
How can i achieve this? I can think of setting some state and prevent loading with `v-if` directive but that seems kind of wrong.

Maybe another solution, can i pass `null` to a parent named view on specific route?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution in case of somebody needs:

```
<-- applies only this one -->
<router-view name="login"></router-view>

<router-view></router-view>

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        login: LoginComp
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Ref : https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-views.html